# Tab bar and Navigation bar disappeared when navigate from Appdelegate

Tags: swift, storyboard

I use Storyboard. When I tried to navigate to another View from AppDelegate, the Tab bar and Navigation bar in that View were disappeared

Here is the code

```
//Some conditions here
let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeView = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(homeView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You're present the `homeView` not push it into `navigation stack` that's why navigation bar and tab bar doesn't show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select **ViewController** from the storyboard.

Go to the Editor and Embed with Navigation Controller **or** Tab Bar Controller

[image]

Give Storyboard ID to your Navigation Controller or Tab Bar Controller

[image]

Assign that Navigation Controller or Tab Bar Controller to Root Viewcontroller from `AppDelegate`.

```
let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let Root_Vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootVc")
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(Root_Vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. So I should use tab-bar's identity instead of the view's.

Comment: @baole Welcome Dear :)

Answer (score 1):

You are just loading the viewcontroller on to the rootview. That's why you can't see tabbar or Navigation bar. You need to present Tabbar or navigation controller in order to see it.

Answer (score 1):

```
let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeView = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")
self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeView)
```

use this code it should work for you